# How to make Gmail automatically convert typed-in or pasted URLs into links

Tags: gmail, google-docs, url

It used to be the case a long time ago that when you type in a URL into a Gmail compose window, and after typing in the last character (or immediately after pasting it in from the clipboard), and typing space, the URL automatically becomes a link.

Then at some point it, they changed the behavior such that typing a space character no longer turns it into a link. I have to select the whole URL with the mouse and type CTRL-k to turn it into a link.

This is the behavior in Google Documents and I would like to re-enable it for Gmail.

Comment: Why would you have a space in the URL? If it's copied from the address bar, the space is already a +, so there is no problem at all.

Comment: @RápliAndrás: There's no space in the URL itself. The Asker is saying that once the URL is written once you get to a word separator (space, period, carriage return) the URL should automatically be converted into an actual link.

Comment: @bgoodr: Is that really necessary, though? Any email client worth its salt is going to convert an URL into a link all on its own.

Comment: Yes it is necessary: Please consider that I paste in links very frequently: When composing a message, I need to verify that the URL I am pasting it resolves correctly. To do that without automatic link creation, I have to take time selecting the URL, typing CTRL-K, moving my hand back to the mouse to then click on the link and click on it again to view it in a new tab in the browser.  All of those key and mouse movements are error-prone.